# Does devenv.com work with extensions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am using this extension (https://github.com/ceztko/SolutionConfigurationName) to put solution output all in one folder. It is working splendidly on our development machines. (I modified the source to support VS2012 installation)

We are now trying to run a build using `devenv.com`, but it seems that the macros are not being evaluated properly --or rather, they are an empty string ""

Does anyone know if devenv.com plays nice with extensions? Or maybe the workflow for a headless build is different such that the extension is not getting triggered? It uses `UpdateSolution_Begin` to update the variables.

tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A headless build won't load that extension, and definitely won't go triggering solution events like that.

To be honest, this feels strongly like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A solution build results in the MSBuild Configuration property being specified to each individual project, and I can't think of any scenario where you wouldn't simply be able to base a build customization on that property. For the Roslyn codebase itself we direct all OutDirs for all projects by simply having a single msbuild .targets file that defines the output path, and then we include that in all projects. Very clean, and doesn't require VS extensions to be installed, or even VS installed at all in order to do a build.

Comment: Yes I agree that it is rather XY... anyway, I have worked around it by having our build server define the `SolutionConfigurationName` and `SolutionPlatformName` macros as environment variables, which VS happily uses in place of the missing values

Comment: Yes, that's another reasonable approach. Best case is still not to rely on solution state, but if you must then the environment variable (or msbuild /p:<whatever>) is the right approach.

Comment: I'm the author of the extension and I found this question, and the env variables workaround, very useful :) . Another guy probably asked me for the same problem, I'll add it as a faq